# Are big-query results always ordered, that is: using OFFSET makes sense to skip rows?

Tags: sql, select, google-bigquery, sql-order-by

In other words does a select query order results every time, so these 2 will always produce unique values:

select *
from `bigquery-public-data.crypto_ethereum.balances`
limit 10 OFFSET 100

select *
from `bigquery-public-data.crypto_ethereum.balances`
limit 10 OFFSET 2000

Assuming of course the table has unique values...I am just curious if without using "order" clause the table is always deterministic/consequetive or can the results duplicate if they're returned indeed at random? 10x!

Comment: Documentation is very clear on this - The rows that are returned by LIMIT and OFFSET are unspecified unless these operators are used after ORDER BY - see more in [LIMIT clause and OFFSET clause](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#limit_clause_and_offset_clause)

Comment: 2023 update, the documentation no longer mentions the need for an ORDER BY.  It is required for the output to work reliably, I'm just saying that the docs no longer mention it. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#limit_and_offset_clause

Comment: I'll also add that most of the time a series of LIMIT OFFSET SELECT statements that attempt to get all of the rows from a table in bigquery do indeed get all of the rows uniquely.  I've just fixed a LIMIT OFFSET SELECT without an ORDER BY in my production system which got through testing and has been there for weeks, and which actually worked for 51 of 52 tables every time and that last one half the time.  I presume it has to do with no data being written around the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am just curious if without using "order" clause the table is always deterministic/consequetive or can the results duplicate if they're returned indeed at random.

No. SQL tables represent *unordered* set of rows. There is no inherent ordering of the rows. Unless an `order by` clause is specified, there is no guarantee that two consequent executive of the same query would yield an indentical result. The database is free to return the rows in whatever order it likes.

As a consequence, the results of a query with a row-limiting clause but no `order by` clause are not deterministic. *Do* add an `order by` clause the these queries, or you will sooner or later run into suprising and hard-to-debug behaviors.

Comment: got it, the only reason i avoided order by is because big-query tells me some limit of resources is reached and order-by is the top consuming part of the query...is there a "non-greedy" clause or something? Or should i dramatically reduce the numbers...

Comment: basically it's a problem when i use order by together with offset...just order by and limit seem to work.

Comment: can u give a sample query . without using offset then how you will run the query in parallel ?